# OTP in Firebase phone auth is not receiving when uploaded on playstore, but works fine when apk is installed on phone directly

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

Added SHA-256 of release and debug mode, updated the google-services.json file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the SHA code from your play store page are well.. go to developer console & get it from Release Management > App Signing